# Printing the HTML generated Identity Card

Tags: php, html

I have created an identity card using HTML and PHP and I want to print it when a button is clicked. But I am not getting idea about what to do next / next step.

Currently I just have the following code. What should I do next that when the `generate_idcard` button is clicked it opens the print dialogue box for printing it.

```
if(isset($_POST['generate_idcard'])){
    $idcard = '<div class="idholder">
                <div class="photobox"><img src="students/'.$f['st_photo'].'" width="102" height="105"></div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt1">'.$f['st_dob'].'</div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt2">'.$f['st_blood'].'</div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt3">'.$f['st_phone'].'</div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt4">'.$f['st_admtype'].'</div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt5">'.$f['st_name'].'</div>
                <img src="images/idcard.png" width="300" height="390">
               </div>';

}
```

Currently, this code when echoed displays the ID card perfectly. I just need to print it now. Please help me on what code to write next to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want as it ?

CSS code for A4 paper size

```
@media print {
    body{
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
        margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm; 

   } 
}
```

Php and html code

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['generate_idcard'])) :?>
               <div class="idholder">
                <div class="photobox"><img src="students/'<?=$f['st_photo']?>" width="102" height="105"></div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt1"><?=$f['st_dob']?></div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt2"><?=$f['st_blood']?></div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt3"><?=f['st_phone']?></div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt4"><?=$f['st_admtype']?></div>
                <div class="idtxt idtxt5"><?=f['st_name']?></div>
                <img src="images/idcard.png" width="300" height="390">
               </div>

            <button onclick="window.print()>print</button>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I said I want to print it... Print it on paper .. A4 Size Paper.. using the printer?

Comment: All you did is change the way I wrote my code.. and let me tell you what you did is an obsolate way which was used in PHP 4..

Comment: I understand how I can more clearly print this code ,I am sory

Comment: Dou u want it for printer @media print {
    body{
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
        margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm; 
        
   } 
}

Comment: I didn't understand how to use your code. Can you please show me by implementing on my code above?

Comment: Not a good code.. You are using the button inside of the PHP code. That PHP code itself runs when a button is clicked so should not add another button inside it as it won't work. Its useless.

Comment: U want trigger other page ?